# Using config! in a handler doesn't work

Tags: clojure, seesaw

I'm writing a GUI, and need to be able to replace a `border-pane`'s `:center` section with another pane. The problem is, the call to `config!` in the handler doesn't have the effect of changing the pane. All other nearly identical calls elsewhere work.

The problem can be summed up as:

```
(ns live-math-pet.gui.mcve
  (:require [seesaw.core :as sc]))

(defn -main []
  (let [; The starting contents
        child1 (sc/label :text "Hello!")
        ; What I want to change to at the click of a button
        child2 (sc/label :text "World!")

        base-pane (sc/border-panel :center child1)

        change-btn (sc/button :listen [:action
                                       (fn [_]
                                         ; This doesn't change the :center area
                                         (sc/config! base-pane :center child2))])

        frame (sc/frame :content base-pane)]

    (sc/config! base-pane :south change-btn)

    ; These work, but the call to config! in the handler doesn't
    (sc/config! base-pane :center (sc/label "Test1"))
    (sc/config! base-pane :center child1)

    (-> frame
      (sc/pack!)
      (sc/show!))))
```

The problem is, this doesn't do anything when I click the button. I expect `config!` to replace the `:center` section, but it doesn't. The click handler is firing, the `config!` just doesn't seem to do anything.

The calls to `config!` at the bottom work, even though the last call is identical.

After searching around, I found a solution, but it kind of rubs me wrong. If I change the handler to

```
(fn [_]
  (sc/replace! base-pane child1 child2)
```

it works. I don't like this for a couple reasons though:

- I need to know what the current contents are. If I don't know, I need to do a lookup, which seems wasteful.
- If I'm giving it the child to replace, presumably it needs to search the parent to find the child. Again, this seems needlessly wasteful.

If `base-pane` was a `frame`, and I wanted to replace its `:content`s using `config!`, it would work as I'd expect.

Why doesn't `config!` work here? Is it necessary to use `replace!`?

---

Updates:

- It turns out the button *is* having an effect, but it only makes the change after resizing the window for some reason.
- When it adds the new panel, it overlays it over the previous one instead of replacing it. It looked like it needed to be repainted, so I tried running `(sc/repaint! (sc/select base-pane [:*]))`, but it didn't make a difference.
- At this point I realized I might just have to use `sc/replace!`, but then ran into the problem of how to get the previous child. `(config base-pane :center)` doesn't work. I think I'm going to have to give each child a class, then use `sc/select`.